# Comparing user inputed string with curdate in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm working on a php/mysql app that strongly rely on a correct date. To ensure that the date inserted into the database is always correct and since php/mysql date functions rely on the system clock, i decide to ask users to input the current date in the date form field and then compare it with the current date in the database using CURDATE() before inserting any data into the database.

I don't know if this is the right way to go about it or is their a better solution to enure date integrity?

Comment: Why do you suspect your system clock might be wrong?  Perhaps you want to look into using [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: cmos battery can fail easily and the user might not notice

Comment: CMOS battery is only useful for maintaining the system clock when a computer is powered down; once it powers back up, tools like ntp (see my link above) can help to restore the clock to a correct time.

Comment: Putting that burden on the user seems to me to be the wrong solution...

Comment: Will ntp be useful offline? Because the application will run offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

One would typically rely on the system clock to be correct; it is something that is much more under one's own control than user input, which can be either deliberately or accidentally incorrect.

I would recommend using `CURDATE()` as a value in your `INSERT` statement, and undertaking measures such as running a [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) client to keep your system clock correct.  Most modern operating systems not only include such software by default, but they are typically configured and working out-of-the-box.

If your system is standalone and unable to update its time from the network, you might consider any combination of: receiving a time signal from another source (such by radio, like the [NPL signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_from_NPL)); verifying the system clock periodically (especially on boot); monitoring the CMOS battery and ensuring that it is replaced in a timely fashion; or employing rechargeable batteries.

Comment: What is the drawback of my method?

Comment: I believe that's answered in my first paragraph - user input "can be either deliberately or accidentally incorrect"; also you must already have some feeling for it being a poor user experience and/or an unreliable method in order to ask the question in the first place?

Comment: Yes. But i don't understand how to use NTP in my application even after checking the link provided. I thought their is a more better programmable way around it.

Comment: @sality: As your system is standalone, NTP is not something you will be able to use.